# Generate a random number which is divisible by 10

Tags: javascript, random

I'm looking for a way to generate a random number that is divisible by 10, such as `10`, `20`, `30`, `40`, `50` and so on…

How could I accomplish this in JavaScript?

Comment: Base 10 is pretty common. I am sure that's not what you mean by 10, 20, 30, 40, 50.

Answer (score 11):

Calculate an integer random number between 1 and 5, and multiply it by 10.

There are *lots* of tutorials out there on how to accomplish the first task. E.g., use

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

(Taken from [Math.random() documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).)

And, as said, multiply the result by 10 … that's it.

So, a complete example might be:

```
function getRandom10() {
  return getRandomInt(1, 5) * 10; // Returns 10, 20, 30, 40 or 50
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

If you need to configure this, use:

```
function getRandom10(min, max) {
  return getRandomInt(min / 10, max / 10) * 10;
}
```

And call it like:

```
getRandom10(30, 70); // => 30, 40, 50, 60 , 70
```